# How to hide the react native focus input border?

Tags: react-native, expo

There would be always a blue border when the text focus. I have already set style borderWidth: 0, but there is still a border. I also tried to set the border color, it won't work either.

Any hint?

Nothing special, I starts from expo tab boilerplate.
Also I found the autofocuse won't be able to triggered either :(

```
import * as React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import EditScreenInfo from "../components/EditScreenInfo";
import { Text, View } from "../components/Themed";

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Tab One</Text>
      <View
        style={styles.separator}
        lightColor="#eee"
        darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"
      />
      <TextInput
        autoFocus={true}
        placeholder="here is a input"
        style={{ padding: 4, borderBottomWidth: 2 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: "80%",
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you paste your code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try setting outlineStyle to 'none'. This will remove all border styles

```
<TextInput style={{outlineStyle: 'none' }} />
```

Comment: It works~! but one more nit is that the system says: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'outlineStyle' does not exist in type 'TextStyle | RecursiveArray<TextStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle>>'.`, so what would be the next?

Comment: Can you please tell me if you develop on the web or native?

Comment: I'm working on both, React Native. The system is actually IDE tool. It is working, but just annoying on the IDE lint warning. Maybe React Native is not officially support it yet.

Comment: This can be, because outlineStyle as TextStyle is only supported on the web. Maybe you can work with Platform.OS and pass the style only if it is web.

Comment: I see... I will check how to tweak the lint on typescript later. #Thanks, @Arbnor.